# Hyperlink formula field to open in the same page

Tags: formula

I have formula field (hyperlink) in contact object to open a record that is related to account object. But the problem is the link opens in new tab and users want them to open in the same page like all other standard salesforce links.

Below is the formula i have used to create the hyperlink.

```
HYPERLINK("/" 
& Account.Firm__c, 
Firm_ID__c)
```

Any suggestions welcome to fix the problem.
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see the following Salesforce.com help page on the HYPERLINK formula function:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000007600&language=en_US

You will want to add a target of "_self".

Answer (score 1):

As per doc :
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#HYPERLINK

> The target parameter is optional. If you do not specify a target, the
>   link opens in a new browser window. Some common target parameters are:
>
> _blank Displays link in a new unnamed window.
>
> _self Displays link in the same frame or window as the element that refers to it.
>   _parent Displays link in the immediate frameset parent of the current frame. This value is the same as _self if the current frame has no
>   parent.
>
> _top Displays link in the full original window, canceling any other frames. This value is the same as _self if the current frame has no
>   parent. For more information on basic HTML tags, consult an HTML
>   reference on the Internet. The HYPERLINK function is available
>   everywhere that you can define a formula except default values, field
>   updates, s-controls, validation rules, approval processes, custom
>   buttons and links, and workflow rules.